# Is this a correct proof that the center of a Hausdorff group is closed?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group and its center be the subgroup $Z = \{ x \in G \; | \; xgx^{-1} = g, \; \forall g \in G \}$. I have already seen the simpler proof [1] that the center is the intersection over all $g \in G$ of the sets $C_g$ of all elements that commute with $g$, and that as the pre-images of the identity under a continuous map, the $C_g$ are all closed and hence so is $Z$.

Here's what I came up with before I looked up the answer. I'd like to know if there are any mistakes. Thanks!

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $Z$ with $x_n \to x$ (the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$). Pick any $g \in G$ and define $f:G \to G$ by $f(x) = xgx^{-1}$. For all $n$, we have $f(x_n) = x_ngx_n^{-1} = x_nx_n^{-1}g = g$ because $x_n \in Z$.

Since $f(x_n)=g$, then $f(x_n)\to g$. Made from multiplication and inversion, $f$ is continuous, so $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Finally, because $G$ is Hausdorff, limits are unique, so $f(x) = g$.

Therefore, $f(x) = xgx^{-1} = g$, implying $xg = gx$, so $x \in Z$. Because any sequence in $Z$ is shown to converge in $Z$, it must be the case that $Z$ is closed.

[1] [Center of compact lie group closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129578/center-of-compact-lie-group-closed/1129596#1129596)

Comment: Your proof holds only for 1st countable spaces.

Comment: Map continuously $G$ to $G^G$ by $c:g\mapsto (ghg^{-1}h^{-1})$, $G^G$ being endowed with the product topology. Then the center is the fiber $c^{-1}(\{1\})$ of the constant function $1$.

Comment: @YCor It would be worth to give an official answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by William elliot, this proof is only applicable to first countable spaces in which

$$x\in\bar A \Leftrightarrow \text{ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ such that } x_n\to x$$

However, we simply need to 'upgrade' the concept of sequences to the concept of [nets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). For general topological spaces, the followings are standard results in which you can try to prove it after learning the definition:

$$x\in\bar A \Leftrightarrow \text{ there exists a net $\{x_\alpha\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ such that 
 } x_\alpha\to x$$

We also have

$$ f \text{ is continuous } \Leftrightarrow x_\alpha\to x \text{ implies }f(x_\alpha)\to f(x)$$

Now, your proof goes through provided that we replace $\{x_n\}$ by $\{x_\alpha\}$.

Comment: You also need that $X$ is Hausdorff iff limits of nets are unique (the easy direction), as did the OP.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right. But the theorem I quoted doesn't require Hausdorffness.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a topological group. For $h\in G$, define $c_h:G\to G$ by $g\mapsto ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$; it is continuous

Then the center of $G$ is $Z(G)=\bigcap_{h\in G}c_h^{-1}(\{1\})$. In particular if $G$ is Hausdorff, $\{1\}$ is closed and hence $c_h^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed, and hence so is the center.

One can essentially restate this using the continuous map $c:G\to G^G$ ($G^G$ being endowed with Tychonov product topology) whose $h$-component is $c_h$. Then $Z(G)=c^{-1}(\{1\})$, where here $1$ is the constant function $1\in G^G$. Again, if $G$ is Hausdorff, $\{1\}$ is closed in $G^G$ and hence $c^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed.

Using inversion is this is a bit cheating because there's an argument working for topological semigroups, and more generally topological magmas (topological magma = topological space $G$ endowed with continuous binary law, where the center is defined as $Z(G)=\{g:\forall h:gh=hg\}$). Let $G$ be a topological magma, and for $h\in G$ define $q_h:G\to G^2$ by $q_h(g)=(gh,hg)$; it is continuous. Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal in $G^2$. Then $Z(G)=\bigcap_{h\in G}q_h^{-1}(\Delta)$. In particular if $G$ is Hausdorff then $Z(G)$ is closed. (Also this can also be restated using an equalizer of two product maps.)